# Best practice for mailing addresses types

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

I am fairly new to GraphQL and i am writing a schema which will include companies and users. Each of these entities will have a mailing address associated with them. I am also using AWS Amplify to generate the resolvers and the DB (at least to get the project going).

- I don't intend to retrieve an address separate from its user/company
- Want to make the schema as modular as possible without repeating information unnecessarily

Here's an abbreviated version of what I started

```
type Address {
  id: ID!
  streetAddress1: String!
  streetAddress2: String
  city: String!
  state: String!
  zipCode: String!
  country: String!
  coordinates: String
}

type Company 
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  address: Address!
  ...
}
```

My question is whether it is best to have the address as a separate type in my schema or to lump each of the company/user types with their own address?
These are my concerns though

- Separating address and entity increases complexity of the business logic and/or mutations.
- In essence, turning the CRUD operations transactional in nature so that both user and address are mutated/queried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I would use an `Address` type without `@model` annotation and no `@connection` from the types that require it.

Comment: If you are asking what best practice is, simply posting what you ended up *doing* isn't necessarily the right answer. It *might* be, if you explain *why* this approach addresses the concerns you raised in the question.